Examine Phrase Search
I am using Examine to Search a list of Microsoft Graph Users.  I'm having trouble with returning the expected results for phrase searches.  A search for "Project Controller" returns all records containing "Project" or "Controller".  When I want only records containing "Project Controller".
My existing Query:
    public async Task<List<User>> Search(string query = "")
    {
        string[] terms = query.Split(' ');
    
        _allUsers = await GetAllUsers();
    
        List<User> matchingUsers = new List<User>();
    
        if (_examineManager.TryGetIndex("ColleaguesIndex", out _colleaguesIndex))
        {
            var searchFields = new[] { "FirstName", "LastName", "DisplayName", "StreetAddress", "JobTitle", "Department", "BusinessUnit", "OfficeLocation", "City", "State", "PostalCode", "BusinessPhones", "MobilePhone", "CompanyName" };
            var results = _colleaguesIndex.Searcher.CreateQuery(defaultOperation: BooleanOperation.Or)
                        .GroupedOr(searchFields, query.MultipleCharacterWildcard()).Or()
                        .GroupedOr(searchFields, query.Escape()).Or()                   
                        .GroupedOr(searchFields, terms)
                        .Execute();
    
            var resultsID = results.Select(r => r.Id);
    
            matchingUsers = _allUsers.Where(u => resultsID.Contains(u.OnPremisesSamAccountName)).ToList();
        }
    
        return matchingUsers;
    }

The resulting query is:
{
    (

        FirstName     : project controller*
        LastName      : project controller*
        DisplayName   : project controller*
        StreetAddress : project controller*
        JobTitle      : project controller*
        Department    : project controller*
        BusinessUnit  : project controller*
        OfficeLocation: project controller*
        City          : project controller*
        State         : project controller*
        PostalCode    : project controller*
        BusinessPhones: project controller*
        MobilePhone   : project controller*
        CompanyName   : project controller*
    )
    (
        FirstName     : "Project controller"
        LastName      : "Project controller"
        DisplayName   : "Project controller"
        StreetAddress : "Project controller"
        JobTitle      : "Project controller"
        Department    : "Project controller"
        BusinessUnit  : "Project controller"
        OfficeLocation: "Project controller"
        City          : "Project controller"
        State         : "Project controller"
        PostalCode    : "Project controller"
        BusinessPhones: "Project controller"
        MobilePhone   : "Project controller"
        CompanyName   : "Project controller"
    )
    (

        FirstName     : project
        FirstName     : controller
        LastName      : project
        LastName      : controller
        DisplayName   : project
        DisplayName   : controller
        StreetAddress : project
        StreetAddress : controller
        JobTitle      : project
        JobTitle      : controller
        Department    : project
        Department    : controller
        BusinessUnit  : project
        BusinessUnit  : controller
        OfficeLocation: project
        OfficeLocation: controller
        City          : project
        City          : controller
        State         : project
        State         : controller
        PostalCode    : project
        PostalCode    : controller
        BusinessPhones: project
        BusinessPhones: controller
        MobilePhone   : project
        MobilePhone   : controller
        CompanyName   : project
        CompanyName   : controller
    )
}

When searching for "Project Controller" I get 68 results.  There are 14 Users with the Job Title = "Project Controllers".
I tried changing .GroupedOr(searchFields, terms) to .GroupedAnd(searchFields, terms).
I tried changing .GroupedOr(searchFields, query.Escape()) to .GroupedAnd(searchFields, query.Escape())
In both cases I end up with 0 results. The problem with changing these to GroupedAnd is I think it's checking to see if ALL fields in my searchFields = "Project Controller".
I simplified my query for testing purposes and I ran this:
var results = _colleaguesIndex.Searcher.CreateQuery().GroupedOr(searchFields, query.Escape()).Execute();

The resulting query is:
LuceneQuery: {+(FirstName:"Project Controller" LastName:"Project Controller" DisplayName:"Project Controller" StreetAddress:"Project Controller" JobTitle:"Project Controller" Department:"Project Controller" BusinessUnit:"Project Controller" OfficeLocation:"Project Controller" City:"Project Controller" State:"Project Controller" PostalCode:"Project Controller" BusinessPhones:"Project Controller" MobilePhone:"Project Controller" CompanyName:"Project Controller")}

...and got 0 results.  That I can't explain.  I would have expected 14 results there.  Needless to say I'm befuddled by how to achieve a phrase search on a group of fields.

Show us the actual query text that _colleaguesIndex.Searcher generates (before you call Execute) - including the first version (where you use GroupedOr) and the second version with GroupedAnd - as well as the full input string query value. BTW, you're calling .Split(' ') before you try to group into phrase-terms - so that's part of your problem right there: don't use String.Split to tokenize searches.

What is searchFields? Your post doesn't define it.

@dai I added the definition for searchFields and the resulting Lucene query of my existing Examine CreateQuery.

I've reformatted your query-text for readability - which in-turn makes it clear (to me, at least) what the problem is.

BTW, your code where you use this  _allUsers.Where(u => resultsID.Contains(u.OnPremisesSamAccountName)). - if _allUsers is an in-memory collection then it's very, very inefficient: it has O(n^2) time-complexity because you're using Enumerable.Contains (which is O(n)) within a .Where which is also O(n).

You're searching for "Project Controller" but the resulting query had the value "Project controller". I'm unfamiliar with Examine, but from what I can find, Searching appears to be case sensitive. Also, if you want to search for Project Controller and Project Controllers, you need to include an escape character, as can be seen in the documentation

@dai "makes it clear...what the problem is."  What is the problem?  The one, I really don't comprehend is why the simplified version for testing didn't work.

@RowanHarley I changed query to query.ToLower() on my simplified testing example and that yielded the result set I expected.
